# How to overwrite Bootstrap 4.5 SASS variables and use them in SCSS files

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, gulp-sass

I am attempting to move all of my CSS files into SCSS files so I can use Bootstrap 4.5 theming to style my site. I previously had some of it working, but once I switched the CSS to SCSS and tried to use custom $theme-color and $color map variables, something is wrong.

I am using Bootstrap 4.5.0, gulp 4.0.2, gulp-sass 4.1.0, node 14.4.0, express 4.17.1, and npm 6.14.5.

I have tried moving my imports around in `bootstrap.scss` to have my variables first, second, third, last. None of them seem to work when I try to use something like `$secondary` in my `custom.scss`. If I create a `<button class="btn btn-secondary">My Button</button>`, it is orange like it is supposed to be. But, when I try to do `footer a:hover { color: $secondary }` it is used Bootstrap's default secondary (grey).

Am I misusing the variables, mis-importing a file, or something completely different?

**variables.scss**

```
$theme-colors: ( 
  "primary": #00A2E2, 
  "secondary":#f16c0e, 
  "danger": #cc0000, 
  "dark-blue": #370dff, 
  "light-blue": #8FD7FF, 
  "light-grey": #e7e7e7, 
  "grey": #666666, 
  "half-dk-blue": #1a0099, 
  "grey-cust": #a5a3a3);
$colors: (
  "light-grey": #e7e7e7,
  "secondary":#f16c0e,
  "dark-blue": #370dff,
  "light-blue": #8FD7FF
);
$font-family-base: "Open Sans",
"Helvetica Neue",
Helvetica,
Arial,
sans-serif;
$font-size-base: 14;
$card-bg: #f5f5f5;
$card-cap-colo: #e7e7e7;
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 480px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 957px
);
```

**bootstrap.scss**

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "./variables.scss";

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

**custom.scss**

```
@import "./bootstrap.scss";

... a lot of styles in here, this is the easiest one to show what the problem is
footer a:hover {
  color: $secondary;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

**custom.css**

```
footer a:hover {
  color: #6c757d;
  text-decoration: none; }
```

**EDIT**
I forgot to include my gulp task

**gulpfile.js**

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var sassFiles = './public/sass/*.scss',
    cssDest = './public/stylesheets/';
gulp.task('styles', function(cb) {
    gulp.src(sassFiles)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
    cb();
});
```

Then I import them in my `head.ejs` like so:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='/stylesheets/custom.css' >
<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css' >
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't import bootstrap in `head.ejs`. Your `custom.css` already contains bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out my problem. I removed the `bootstrap.js` import from my `head.ejs` and instead of doing

```
footer a:hover {
  color: $secondary;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

I needed to do

```
footer a:hover {
  color: theme-color("secondary");
  text-decoration: none
}
```